# Calculating Average within same system id

Tags: spotfire

I have a data set with the columns `Filament` and `System id`:

```
Filament     System id
102                    1
107                    1
534                    2
235                    1
```

I need to create a calculated column which shows the average `Result` like this:

```
Filament     System id               Result 
102                    1             102
107                    1             (102+107)/2
534                    2             534
235                    1             (102+107+235)/3
```

How can I calculate this average column?

Comment: Hello! I edited your text to make it slightly more readable. Mostly just a little grammar. I also added backticks ` around important words.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a new column (`Row_ID`) with the Row number:
   `RowId()`
2. Expression for the result:
   `Avg([Filament]) over (Intersect(allPrevious([row_ID]),[System id]))`

[image]